# Nested Components and Proper Wrapping Techniques in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to put Bootstrap Select2 in a Vue wrapper. Somehow, my code works. But It doesn't seem proper to me.

I found a reference in here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html
In the VueJS website example, the el is empty. I didn't stick to this concept where in the new Vue part, they included a template because my el have sidebars and other stuffs also. What I did was I added a

```
<admin-access></admin-access>
```

to a section in the HTML.

I think I made my component nested which I'm skeptical if it is proper in VueJS.

Is there a better way to code this?

**Templates**

```
<template id="select2-template">
    <select>
        <slot></slot>
    </select>
</template>

<template id="admin-access">
    <div>
        <transition name="access" enter-active-class="animated slideInRight" leave-active-class="animated slideOutRight" appear>
            <div class="box box-solid box-primary" v-if="admin" key="create">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <i class="fa fa-text-width"></i>
                    <h3 class="box-title">Create Admin</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <form action="" class="search-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="search_user_admin">Search User</label>
                            <select2 name="search_user_admin" id="search-user-admin" class="form-control select2" :options="options" v-model="selected">
                                <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
                            </select2>
                        </div>
                        
                    </form>
              </div>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Script**

```
Vue.component('admin-access', {
    template: '#admin-access',
    props: ['options', 'value'],
    created: function() {
        $('#search-user-admin').select2({
            placeholder: "Select User",
            allowClear: true
        });
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            admin : true,
            selected : false
        }
    },
});

Vue.component('select2', {
    template: '#select2-template',
    data: function() {
        return {
            selected: 0,
            options: [
                { id: 1, text: 'Hello' },
                { id: 2, text: 'Darkness' },
                { id: 3, text: 'My' },
                { id: 4, text: 'Old' },
                { id: 5, text: 'Friend' }
            ]
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        var vm = this;
        $(this.$el).select2({
            data: this.options,
            placeholder: "Select an option",
        })
        .val(this.value)
        .trigger('change')
        .on('change', function () {
        vm.$emit('input', this.value);
      });
    },
    watch: {
        value: function (value) {
            $(this.$el).val(value).trigger('change');
        },
        options: function (options) {
            $(this.$el).select2({ data: options });
        }
    },
    destroyed: function () {
        $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy');
    }
});

var admin = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with nesting components.

Comment: @retrograde then is my code structure above okay?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with nesting components in the first place. But you have to keep in mind that nesting them, or just in general, just wrapping generic html components like a select into a Vue Component is very costly when it comes to rendering, especially when you are nesting them. Typically when all your component does is just wrapping a simple HTMl element with some styles, you should probably just use generic HTML with classes here, for performance sake.

Also, I'd try to get rid of all the jQuery code inside of Vue Components. Vue offers all the functionality that jQuery has and it'll just increase loading times further.

Comment: My template relies on Bootstrap and Jquery so I can't really remove it. I just use VueJS to make my life easier on data bindings and animation stuffs on my project, and also to study and differentiate vue with JQuery.